# Add options to Sub-category attribute in Magento 1

Tags: attributes, product-attribute, admin-panel, dropdown-attribute, sub-categories

I want to add additional option to the subcategory attribute but I cannot locate where to update its content within the Magento Admin Panel.

[image]
See this link for full image - https://drive.google.com/open?id=16sFqr_i_9jRyAs4yDTwAVPeDIkfAz0Il

Currently, I have no access to the backend/module files, so I am not sure if its hardcoded or can be edited within the admin panel.

Please help. I am very new to Magento.

Thank you

Comment: Have you got the answer of your query?

Answer (score 0):

In order to update the already created custom attribute. you need to update your module script name which will create your custom category attribute

```
mysql4-Upgrade-OldversionNo-VersionNO.php
```

you also need to change the version in your module config.xml. let say new version s 0.0.2

```
<version>0.0.2</version
```

Update script by adding options in category attribute and clear the cache. script will trigger and new option will be added in category attribute.

**I hope this will help**